# hide validation error when an input receives focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code:
        - here i've declared my variables:

```
    var first = $('#first');
    var firstError = $('#firsterror'); // the errors are in span tags (if it matters)
    // and so on... 
    first.blur(validateFirst);
    last.blur(validateLast);
    username.blur(validateUsername);
    password.blur(validatePassword);
    confpassword.blur(validateConfpassword);
    month.blur(validateMonth);
    day.blur(validateDay);
    year.blur(validateYear);
    gender.blur(validateGender);

    $('#myForm').submit(function(){
   if( validateFirst() & validateLast() & validateUsername() & validatePassword() &     validateConfpassword() & validateMonth() & validateDay() & validateYear() &   validateGender() ){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    });

    function validateFirst(){
      if(first.val().length < 5){
        first.addClass('error_input');
        firstError.text('You left this empty!');
        firstError.addClass('error');
        return false;
      }else{
        first.removeClass('error_input');
        firstError.text('');
        return true;
      }
    };
      // and so on...  I would like the code to work as so: When an input recives focus the error should hide else the code should run exactly as it is.
```

thank you..

Comment: Can you show us the HTML?

Comment: The html looks like this:<input type="text" id="last" title="Enter your last name." placeholder="Last"/><span id="errorfirst"></span>                 This is just for an input...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use jQuery validate lib to validate your form here is cdn link of jQuery validate..

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Note that you have to include jQuery lib before that line

All you have to do is just write few lines of code as below

```
$('#form_id').validate({
    rules : {
        'el_name' : 'validation_rule'  // like, required
    },
    messages : {
        'el_name' : 'Your error message'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try something like this already?

```
function removeError() {
     $(this).removeClass('error_input');
     $("#error"+$(this).attr("id")).text("").removeClass("error");
}

first.focus(removeError);
last.blur(removeError);
username.blur(removeError);
....
```

Comment: @user1970355 do you also need to remove the error text? if yes does the error span always have the id error + the name of the field ?

Comment: Well the error is still there... the 'error_input'class works only for the input field and the 'error' class work for the span...

Comment: @user1970355 updated my answer, will this work correct for first ?

Comment: it works great but if i replace the name atribute with id. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Paul Harbuz  oh yes .. sorry .. did recognized that it was id and not name. fixed it and updated the answer with the info how to reuse it for the other fields

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this

```
$('.error_input').focus(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('.error_input');
});
```